# Change data according to selected item in combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, populate

I call into a function which runs a query into SQLServer and returns a DataTable with multiple columns. I want the data from the DataTable to change rows according to the selected item in the combobox.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim rInt As New Int32

dt = subGetDB()
rInt = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex
Textbox1.Text = dt.Rows(rInt)("description").ToString()
TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(rInt)("accountFilter").ToString()
```

Am I on the right track with this so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes ... but you need to put all of the code above into the SelectedValueChanged event for the ComboBox1 object.